# Angularjs -- change view based on browser/platform?

Tags: angularjs

Is there any in-built services/directives/routes to change the view (or page using routing) based on the type of browser/platform the user is accessing from?  I'd like phones and tablets to have a different view than desktop users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know of anything built into Angular, but you can do this by inserting logic into your routing rules. For example:

```
angular.module('browser-routing', []).
  config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {templateUrl: getBrowser() + '.html'})
});
```

In this example, if getBrowser() returns `'iphone'` it will render the view `iphone.html`

You can use 
[BrowserDetect](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) to do what the name implies.

[fiddle example for Chrome and Firefox detection](http://jsfiddle.net/5dWYW/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Although AngularJS does not have any particular feature to do that out-of-the-box, there are many different approaches to accomplishing something like that:

1. Using [CSS3 media queries to make a responsive design](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/entry/code_example_of_responsive_web_design_using_css3_media_queries13?lang=en). Depending on your needs, this may be your best bet, as you can avoid re-implementing features for multiple viewports.
2. You can write a service to check and make the route change:

   ```
   myApp.factory('checkWidth', function ($location, $window) {
     return function () {
       if ($window.document.width < 700) {
         $location.url('/mobile');
       }
     }
   });
   ```